# What does "Abstraction of function application" mean?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm reading [this book](https://mostly-adequate.gitbook.io/mostly-adequate-guide/ch08), and the author is saying:
"Well, abstraction of function application. When we map a function, we ask the container type to run it for us. This is a very powerful concept, indeed."

How's Abstraction of function application is that powerful? I have some vague thoughts about this. So if you have more solid answer, I'd highly appreciate it!
Thanks

Comment: Abstraction of function application in different functorial contexts. A functorial context is a type that implements functor on the term level and complies with its laws. Each functorial type encodes an individual effect and how to invoke a function in this effectful context: How to invoke a function that maps over the codomain of another function? How to invoke one that might yield no result? How to invoke one that might yield 0..n results? How to invoke one that defers evaluation? Functor abstracts from these details. You can simnply apply your pure function in any lawful context.

Comment: That actually makes sense! So it's all about reusability?

Comment: Yes, reusability plus encoding effects as values of certain types. Effects as values are first class and explicit. Along with a uniform interface (functor/applicative/monad) you gain a great deal of predictability/reliability of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the application of a function to the value(s) inside a container is abstracted away from the "mapper".

Do you have to know the difference between how one iterates a Set vs an Array vs a Map vs the individual characters of a string in Javascript? No, because they all implement the same iterator interface (i.e. implement the [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) protocol). You can use `for...of` on any of them, off you go.

The author is making the same point here about functors. In OO languages `.map` is a method of objects, and in functional languages it's an [ad-hoc polymorphic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism), but the idea is the same either way: you give a container a function (or give fmap a function and a container) and it knows how to take care of itself.

Consider the following with two of the built-in Javascript container types:

```
Promise.prototype.map = Promise.prototype.then;

const foo = Promise.resolve('1');
const bar = ['1'];
foo.map(Number); // Promise of 1
bar.map(Number); // Array of 1
```

When we call `.map` we get back a new container of the same type of the old container with the transformed value inside, whether the container is a Promise or an Array or whatever (note that just like in my examples the type of the *value inside the container* may have changed).

As I said above the details of how the transform function is applied to the value in the container is abstracted away from the caller. I (and more importantly the transform function I pass in) don't have to know the specifics of how `.map` is implemented for Promises vs. Arrays or how to re-wrap the transformed value in a container: the container (or polymorphic stand-alone map function) knows how to do that for us.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification! It makes more sense now indeed. Sorry if that was answered but not clear for me. Why is that powerful? To abstract the caller from the callee? Is it related to reusability of callees (mappers)?

Comment: It's powerful because very, very *few* people know how `Promise.prototype.then` is actually implemented, but very very *many* use it every day to solve problems. Functors are like any other good abstraction: they lower the bar on how much you need to understand in order to be able to get stuff done. And, (and this is crucially important) *they can be implemented in any language that supports higher-order functions AKA first-class functions*. Which is most of them these days. And they create a language-agnostic vocabulary. There was a fad once upon a time calling these things "design patterns".